# Can Unicorn Listen to a File Descriptor?

Tags: ruby, unicorn

Can the Unicorn Rack server listen to an existing file descriptor?
If not, are there any Rack servers that can?

For example, I have a parent process that opens port `80` as file descriptor `3` then forks and executes Unicorn. Can Unicorn choose to listen to the pre-opened socket?

Answer (score 1):

You can manualy set socket to listen method in config file, 
for example

`listen Socket.for_fd(ENV['FD'])`